# How to modify a loadable kernel module without recompiling whole kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kvm

I have to do some modifications in the `kvm` module of linux kernel, which is a loadable module. However I wish to do this without having to recompile the entire kernel source.

I know that firstly the module has to be unloaded using `modprobe -r` and in the end, the module has to be reloaded using `modprobe`. However I am not clear regarding what to do in between these two steps.

Can someone specify what exactly needs to be done in between unloading and reloading of the module? My machine details are as follows:

- **Linux Distro:** Ubuntu 12.04
- **Linux version:** `3.14.2`

Comment: `cd /usr/src/linux; make modules && make modules_install`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Do I have to execute these steps after doing the appropriate modification in the module's code? Also won't `make modules` compile all the modules as opposed to a single module which I want to change? Can you be a bit specific?

Comment: You should get familiar with `make`, it's a great tool. In short, yes, you have to modify the module before recompiling it, and no, `make` will only rebuild modules whose source code (or dependencies) have changed since the last build.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Also, I have put my kernel sources in a folder different from `/usr/src`. In such a case, do I still have to `cd` to `/usr/src/linux` as the first step, or do I have to `cd` to the directory where I have put my sources?

Comment: The answer is in your question. Of course you have to navigate to the right directory, I only mentioned the "standard" location of the Linux sources.

Comment: Yeah, it was kind of trivial, but I had to clarify just to be extra sure. Thanks for that input :)